# What does hidden windows mean?

Tags: macos, mac, mission-control, expose

Mission control supposed to show **everything** running on Mac. The definition for Mission Control given by this website also confirms that (see the screen shot shown bellow. **EDIT: This has now been corrected after this question**).

[image]

But, I cannot see the hidden windows in my Mission Control. What am I missing?

EDIT: [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100) says *Mission Control is the quick way to see **everything that's currently open on your Mac***. Does this mean hidden windows are closed? What does actually hidden windows mean?

Comment: If Mission Control will not show anything hidden, how can you define it as "...one place to see and navigate **everything** running on your Mac" (see the screen shot in my question)? **Are you saying the definition given for Mission Control in this website is wrong?**

Comment: You shouldn't take a tag description on a web site not affiliated with Apple as a feature description. See http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100 for how Apple defines Mission Control.

Comment: This question made an opportunity to improve the definition given to the tag _mission-control_ in this website, I am proud of that and thank you for editing the definition.

Comment: I've uprooted this since it might really have an actual question. What does "hidden windows" mean - could you edit your post to explain what you think of as a window that's hidden? (Or link to an Apple KB article describing that feature?)

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mission Control is the quick way to see everything that's currently
>   open on your Mac.

The above statement from the Apple help page **WAS** true, but now it is **OUTDATED**. Mission Control used to show all open windows including hidden ones, but Apple excluded hidden windows from the list in the recent versions of OS X. But the documentation is not updated yet.

(About your 2nd question: Hidden windows are not closed windows, they are open ones, but you cannot see them until you make them unhidden. Please note hidden windows are shown in app expose)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't take a tag description on a web site not affiliated with Apple as a feature description. See http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100 for how Apple defines Mission Control (emphasis mine):

> Mission Control is the quick way to see everything that's currently open on your Mac. To use Mission Control, do one of the following:
>
> - Swipe up with three or four fingers on your Trackpad
> - Double-tap the surface of your Magic Mouse with two fingers
> - Click the Mission Control icon in the Dock or Launchpad
> - On an Apple keyboard, press the Mission Control key
>
> In Mission Control, all of your **open** windows and spaces are visible, grouped by app.

Comment: You seem to be assuming hidden windows are closed, but they are still open (but not visible).